# How do I get a DbContextOptions<T> in ASP.NET MVC Core 7.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm following a tutorial on dialogs that I want to use in my ASP.NET MVC Core application, but I need to provide my SQL Server database.

Tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aKrzBR32pKk

In my `appsettings.json`, I have my connection string:

```cs
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "Mvc1Context": "Data Source=data.somewhere.com;Initial Catalog=myDatabase;User Id=dbAdmin;Password=dbP@ssw0rd"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

*The connection string is not real. It illustrates that I am not using a local database or an Azure database like all of the examples I have found.*

In my `Program.cs` file, I think I have the right way to get the connection string:

```cs
using Mvc1.Data;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

    // Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

var app = builder.Build();
// setup the database
var conn = $"{app.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Mvc1Context")}";
```

But, I don't know how to test it yet.

At about 2 minutes, the video shows initializing the class with an *[ApplicationDbContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/)*, but there is no information on how to get this item:

[screenshot of tutorial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGcQv.png)

This new setup of Microsoft's seems overly complicated. I am used to ASP.NET Framework 4.5x where I just read in from the string on a `Web.config`, open the connection using new *[SqlConnection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection)*, and then read or write data to the SQL Server.

Since none of the examples show this, does this tell me that I need to access my remote SQL Server differently? Is the ASP.NET MVC Core 7.0 way better (more efficient or more secure)?

Could someone show me an easy way to get the connection string and access the SQL Server in ASP.NET MVC Core 7.0?

I am trying to read up on information, but it is all so different from what I used in the past that I am having trouble understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to register the DbContext in the dependency injection container.

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(
    options => options.UseSqlServer(YourConnectionString)); //This can be SQL Server or any other databse provider.

var app = builder.Build();
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/ has some really good content with examples which will help you to get started with EF Core.

Comment: When it tries to read the **AddDbContext**, I get: `**System.InvalidOperationException:** 'The service collection cannot be modified because it is read-only.'` What is read-only and how do I undo that?

Comment: Are you still mangling with `builder.Services` after calling `builder.Build()`?

Comment: Sorry. I can't upvote until I have over 50 score. And, after I get the information working in the **Program.cs** file, how am I expected to get the database information to other controllers like `Controllers\HomeController.cs`?

Comment: Yes: Trying to get `builder.Services` after calling `builder.Build()` because that is where I get **app** for pulling my connection string: `var conn = app.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Mvc1Context");`

Comment: You can pull your connection string by calling `builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Mvc1Context")`

Comment: That exception happens because you're adding to the service collection after the call to Build(). Did you try starting from working code (in the tutorial) and going from there?

Answer (score 1):

From the tutorial you provided, Author is using Dependency Inject to inject `ApplicationDbContext` into controller. Before you inject `ApplicationDbContext` into controller, You need to register `ApplicationDbContext` into Service container first. You can simply split `Program.cs` into two parts:

```
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

            //part 1

            var app = builder.Build();

            //part 2
```

Part 1 is for user to Add services to the container. Part 2 is for user to Configure the HTTP request pipeline. So here you need to register `ApplicationDbContext` into part 1:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext >(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Mvc1Context")));
```

Now you can inject `ApplicationDbContext` into your controller correctly.

Comment: How would I then access the `ApplicationDbContext` from my **HomeController** (or other controllers). All of the examples I see show the controllers being populated with the `ApplicationDbContext` in the constructor, but my code always tells me that the object is null.

Comment: could you share the full error message?